# Include request data in Django Rest Framework custom exception handler response data

Tags: python, django, error-handling, django-rest-framework, django-errors

**Tech used:**

http://www.django-rest-framework.org

**Exceptions:** http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/

Included rest_framework default example in custom exceptions.py file:

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

import sys

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context=None):

    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc)

    # Now add the HTTP status code to the response and rename detail to error
    if response is not None:
        response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code
        response.data['request'] = request
        response.data['error'] = response.data.get('detail')
        del response.data['detail']

    return response
```

This sends basic error info like "Http404" etc, but no request data, like ip address, etc.

Best way to add my request into the response? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE (and solved):**

So, I was initially trying to solve this using DjangoRestFramework 2.4.x, but that version doesn't have the request or context data options for the custom exception handler. Upgrading to 3.1.3 made it easy to add the data into the response. New code now looks like this (using version 3.1.3):

```
def custom_exception_handler(exc, request):

# Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
# to get the standard error response.
response = exception_handler(exc, request)

# Send error to rollbar
rollbar.report_exc_info(sys.exc_info(), request)

# Now add the HTTP status code to the response and rename detail to error
if response is not None:
    response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code
    response.data['error'] = response.data.get('detail')
    del response.data['detail']

return response
```

Comment: Please check the indentation of `response = exception_handler(exc)`. Is it correct?

Comment: Thanks Rahul - yeah its correct - just looks wrong with how I pasted it here

Answer (score 5):

This should work for your case.

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

import sys

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context=None):

    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc)

    # Now add the HTTP status code to the response and rename detail to error
    if response is not None:
        response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code
        response.data['request'] = context['request']
        response.data['error'] = response.data.get('detail')
        del response.data['detail']

    return response
```

You can access the `request` from the context passed to the `custom_exception_handler`. This was added in **DRF 3.1.0**. Also refer this [issue](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2236) where it was resolved.

**If you are using DRF<3.1, there would be no `request` in the context of exception handler. You can upgrade to DRF 3.1.3(latest version in [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorestframework/3.1.3)) and then easily access the `request` in context.**

**Taken from DRF 3.1.1 source code:**

```
def get_exception_handler_context(self):
    """
    Returns a dict that is passed through to EXCEPTION_HANDLER,
    as the `context` argument.
    """
    return {
        'view': self,
        'args': getattr(self, 'args', ()),
        'kwargs': getattr(self, 'kwargs', {}),
        'request': getattr(self, 'request', None)
    }
```

Also, you need to configure the exception handler in your `settings.py` file.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

If it is not specified, the `'EXCEPTION_HANDLER'` setting defaults to the standard exception handler provided by REST framework:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'rest_framework.views.exception_handler'
}
```

**Note:**

> Exception handler will only be called for responses generated by
>   raised exceptions. It will not be used for any responses returned
>   directly by the view, such as the HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST responses that
>   are returned by the generic views when serializer validation fails.

Comment: Thanks Rahul - I actually have that already, but the request needs to be defined...

Comment: Hi Rahul - yup I've added the exception handler to my settings.py file already too - but still can't get that info... thanks agian for your help

Comment: Try accessing `request` by `context['request']` if that works.

Comment: I'm getting 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Try putting a debugger like `ipdb` in `custom_handler_exception` in your code and see what you are getting in `context`.

Comment: hey @Rahul - I dug a little more and its because Django Rest Framework does have the context variable available in the exception handler. it's available in Django's custom exception process but not Django rest framework

Comment: Hi @Rahul - I'ved upgrade to Django 3.1.0 but now I'm getting this error:exception_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context' I'm passing in (exc, request). I've also tried (exc, context) and (exc, context=None)

Comment: This was a bug in DRF 3.0.2. Check out this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180738/custom-exception-handler-not-working-as-documented-in-django-rest-framework  and this link    https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2737.  This should have been resolved in DRF 3.1. Try DRF 3.1.1 also.

Comment: Hi where to add this customException.py file..? I am getting error like Could not import my_project.myapp.customException for API setting EXCEPTION_HANDLER. ImportError: No module named myapp.

Comment: In the above code, `custom_exception_handler` is in `utils.py` file in the django app .You can also create a file `exceptions.py` in your django app and then  import it in your DRF settings like `my_project.my_app.exceptions.custom_exception_handler` .